# Why CoCreateInstance can return two different HRESULT in the exact same context?

Tags: c++, com, directshow

I want to use [DSound Audio Render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/directsound-renderer-filter) in one of my application so I load it with [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance). According to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54772340/why-cocreateinstance-returns-regdb-e-classnotreg-on-some-windows), `CoCreateInstance` can return `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` if I have no audio hardware installed. But if I call `CoCreateInstance` a second time, I doesn't have the same `HRESULT`. Here is a little example (to reproduce it, you should disable all of your audio devices in the device manager of Windows):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <strmif.h>
#include <uuids.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;

    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    printf("CoInitialize = 0x%x\n", hr);

    IBaseFilter* ptr = NULL;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DSoundRender, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&ptr);

    printf("CoCreateInstance = 0x%x\n", hr);

    if(ptr)
        ptr->Release();

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DSoundRender, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&ptr);

    printf("CoCreateInstance = 0x%x\n", hr);

    if(ptr)
        ptr->Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    std::cout << "End" << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
}
```

I get this result:

```
Start
CoInitialize = 0x0
CoCreateInstance = 0x80040154
CoCreateInstance = 0x80040256
End
```

The first error code `0x80040154` corresponds to `REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG` so it is coherent with [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54783166/7334162) I got in my previous question but the second error code `0x80040256` corresponds to `VFW_E_NO_AUDIO_HARDWARE`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/error-and-success-codes):

> **VFW_E_NO_AUDIO_HARDWARE**
>   0x80040256
>
> Cannot play back the audio stream:
>   no audio hardware is available, or the hardware is not supported.

So why do I have the meaningful error only the second time I call `CoCreateInstance`? What can I change to have this error at the first call?

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite ptr w/o releasing it first. Have you tried to add ptr->Release() before the 2nd call to CoCreateInstance? Not sure it's related in anyway, as I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @SimonMourier It's useless in that case because ptr is NULL when an error occured. But, you're right, it's safer.

Comment: @SimonMourier To reproduce it, you should disable all of your audio devices in the device manager of Windows.

Comment: It could've been done better but since you are not supposed to `CoCreateInstance` this directly anyway it is not really even a bug. I am pretty sure the behavior with device enumerator will be consistent and as documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want documented and consistent behavior then you should not cut corners and go along suggested lines, which are: [Using the System Device Enumerator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/directshow/using-the-system-device-enumerator).

Enumeration of devices in audio renderer category will get you a moniker object for "Default DirectSound Device" and then your `IMoniker::BindToObject` would result in meaningful `VFW_E_NO_AUDIO_HARDWARE` (both on the first call and the following ones).

You can also see this in action without writing code: you can use GraphStudioNext app, menu Graph, Insert Filter, "Audio Renderers" category in the combo box, then double click on "Default DirectSound Device" entry trying to instantiate the filter.

As for the tagline question about different codes, here is my educated guess. The error code eventually comes from software. You had a chance to see that COM server is present in the system, so COM subsystem does start instantiation, then fails in the middle and forwards you the failure code back. It is likely that COM server has a singleton or otherwise a cached enumeration of hardware. In your first attempt it hits "no devices" condition during initialization and aborts instantiation at an earlier step, so COM reports inability to create an instance. Next time the server already sees its cached enumeration (that is, it is not "exactly the same context" as you assumed) and skips the initial failure point, but then again stumbles on a next check.

There is nothing you can do about this, especially that you were supposed to instantiate `CLSID_DSoundRender` differently in first place.